# Nextjs category and subcat without prefix routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to Next.js and want to create such a routing in Next.js like this:

```
localhost:3000/mobile/ios/apple/ipone-14
Cat---------------^
SubCat----------------^
Brand----------------------^
Product--------------------------^
```

As you see there is no prefix here, so I can't create any folder in `pages` so I should create slug file in root, right?

`[slug].js` is category, `[...slug].js` is subcategory, what about brand and product? Is this right way? And what is best practice to create such routing in Next.js?

For example, if you open this page:

```
localhost:3000/mobile/android/samsung/samsung-s22
```

It should show the product page, and if you open:

```
localhost:3000/mobile
```

it should show all products on this category, and:

```
localhost:3000/mobile/android
```

Should show all product with this subcategory. And one important thing: I have other pages like:

```
localhost:3000/aboutus
```

I don't want to recognize this as category. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [exportPathMap](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap)

What you need is `exportPathMap`, do not create `folder` or `slug.js` file, instead in your `next.config.js` file try to put this:

```
module.exports = {
  exportPathMap: async function (
      defaultPathMap,
      { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
  ) {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' },
      '/:slug': { page: '/category'},
      '/:slug/:slug': { page: '/subcategory'},
      '/:slug/:slug/:slug': { page: '/brand'},
      '/:slug/:slug/:slug/:slug': { page: '/product'},
    }
  }
}
```

Now create `category.js`...`product.js` and etc to display your desire content. Note that, with this approach you can't use something like `/aboutus`, because this will cause interference!

## Or

Create folder in `pages` inside each other like this:

```
-[category]
-index.js
--[subcategory]
--index.js
---[brand]
---index.js
----[product]
----index.js
```